# Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes at heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, mongoid, rack, mongohq

I uploaded a Sinatra app to heroku. Before that, I installed the free `MongoHQ` addon there. However, I have an error from heroku:

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure - Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

Here is my mongoid.yml

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: my_db
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        timeout: 10
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

So, why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `heroku config` you will see if heroku has added a MONGOHQ_URL which your mongoid.yml references.  The other possiblity is you haven't set your RACK_ENV=production via `heroku config:add RACK_ENV=production`

Can you show us the output of running `heroku config`?